# using jQuery to pull in emails from Gmail DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, gmail

I want to target all the span's off the Gmail DOM and pull the 'email' value's into an array.

```
<span class="yP" email="han@mFalcon.com" name="Han Solo">\Han Solo</span>
```

I fear the javascript/jQuery below doesn't work because of all the nesting that is happening in the Gmail DOM. Any feedback is appreciated!

PS: this code is being used in a Chrome Extension where jQuery is being loaded as well.

```
var emailArray = $("span[class^=yP]").map (
    function (index) {
        var idVal = $(this).attr('email');
        return [idVal];
    }
).get ();

console.log (emailArray);
```

Comment: You do know that, the DOM structure of the Gmail page can change any time. Don't you? If you are doing this just on your own assuming that things don't change, your code might stop working one day!

Comment: @Teja I do realize this :) but open to other suggestions of how this might be done. I was considering using the Gmail API, but I don't want to oAuth.

Comment: Well, in that case I would try and answer later today :)

Comment: I can't find a similar dom structure when I tried to inspect. Can you add an image indicating which version of gmail are you using? (like basic html or any other)